# The person who works for a University while studying there

Tags: names

What do you call a student at a University who gets hired by the University part time to do tasks around the university such as watching the front desk.  Is there an official title for students like this or do we just describe it like a student who works part time at his university?

Comment: "_Student Volunteers_"?

Comment: But the University pays, just not a lot.  Sometimes they also offer other perks also.

Comment: Maybe an '_Internship_'? An Intern, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

In US colleges these are usually called 'work-study' or 'work/study' positions, as are the people who hold the positions.

> We've got three new work-studies at the front desk this term.

Answer (score 0):

Varun is right!

'Intern' could be one of the words, if not *the* word.

Though the term has been widely used for *medicos,* I have heard and seen students or graduates doing *internship* in and off the campuses.

Interns are *generally* paid.